# Do query loads all the data in memory

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa

Whenever we execute a query does Hibernate/JPA load all the data in memory? Does it do some kind of optimization by itself or does it have some kind of mechanism where it fetches the query data in batch?

So here just my concern is, if I have a table with millions of rows, how hibernate manages those rows, will all the rows be loaded in memory at once if I don't specify any optimization strategy?

I am using Oracle as database.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `org.hibernate.Query.list` Hibernate will load all mapped objects into memory. You can avoid this by using `org.hibernate.Query.scroll` instead. You can then scroll through the `ScrollableResults` and evict entities from your session after you're finished with them.

Doing this will avoid loading all the entities into memory and will avoid issues with dirty checking a very large session.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever we execute a query does hibernate / jpa loads all the data in memory?

No, it queries the database just like you would manually. It only loads in memory the result set of that query.

> Do it do some kind of optimization by itself or do it have some kind of mechanism where it fetches the query data in batch?
>
> So here just my concern is, if I have a table with millions of rows how hibernate manages those rows if I fetch them by using JPQL or HQL?

Hibernate translates the JPQL or HQL in its equivalent SQL query.

So if you have a JPQL like

```
SELECT p FROM Person WHERE p.id = 99
```

Hibernate will translate it into (probably*) something like

```
SELECT P.id, P.name, P.address, P.<other-mapped-fields> FROM TB_Person P WHERE P.id = 99
```

Thus if the `TB_Person` table has millions of rows, only one row should (probably*) be fetched. Hibernate then would only load *that* row into memory and map it into an object.

<sub>* I'm saying *probably* because you can have complicated mappings, like embeddeds and joins, in your entity - which could, naturally, require more than one database table to rebuild your instances.</sub>

Comment: what if I write a query like `from Person p` and person table has millions of rows, will all of them be fetched into memory at once?

Comment: Yes, they will. The `from Person p` JPQL is translated to `SELECT P.<all-mapped-fields> FROM TB_Person P`, thus bringing everything that table has in the database (in your case, Oracle).